# Which timezone is selected when Timestamp is put in StackOverFlow database

Tags: dataexplorer

When I use the Stack Exchange data explorer tool (https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new) for querying data related to the timestamp of the questions, the retrieved value is in which timezone?

Will all the values that are shown be in UTC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe everything is in UTC. Someone asked that same question in the link before on Meta Stack Exchange. It discusses it a bit further but the basic answer to your question is UTC.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42179/what-time-zone-do-sos-servers-operate-in